# Difftime function always give me 0

Tags: r, posix, difftime

I am pretty new to R and programming... 
So I had a couples of dates in my dataset with this format `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"` as stored as chr, so I used this to convert it to the format i want.

```
 x <- as.POSIXct(data$data , format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
data$data <- format(x, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
 x <- as.POSIXct(data$data1 , format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
    data$data1 <- format(x, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

Now I want the time diference between both times, so I use:

```
x <- difftime(data$data, data$data1 ,units = "mins")
```

And When I try to view `x` it gives me 0.
In adition my `data$data` and `data$data1` are still chr, is this normal? 
Am I missing any step?

Comment: Can you post the head of your data please

Comment: Your Dates should be `POSIXct` after the transformation. You probably got the format wrong. As @Sam pointed out, a sample of  your data would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert them `as.POSIXct`, then use `format` to change them:

```
data$data <- as.POSIXct(data$data , format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
data$data1 <- as.POSIXct(data$data1 , format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")

data$data <- format(data$data, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
data$data1 <- format(data$data1, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

Comment: for some reason, that does not work neither. For some reason the X works

Comment: @InêsMierPelaez, Could you provide a minimal data? If I use the code above data <- data.frame(data="2018-10-20 05:02:23", data1="2018-09-10 12:20:30") it works.